# How can I filter events by user properties on firebase analytics

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I have created firebase analytics for my mobile app. So I set some user properties like age, gender, jobs. My question is how can I filter events (like screen_open) on this properties?

I have tried send properties with params in logEvent function.
I want to show events by user